# Include JS libraries in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/frontend) page of documentation on how to include a library like JQuery. I proceeded like this:

```
npm install jquery
npm run dev
```

Since JQuery didn't become magically available after this, I looked around, and there it is referenced and used in `public/js/app.js`. So I used the following line in my master layout file, and now I can use JQuery.

```
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

I did not see such a *workaround* anywhere online, so my question is, am i doing it right? Furthermore I get this error in the Console:

> TypeError: window.Laravel is undefined[Learn More]
>        http://localhost/js/app.js:1697:1
>       **webpack_require** http://localhost/js/app.js:20:12
>        http://localhost/js/app.js:778:1
>       **webpack_require** http://localhost/js/app.js:20:12
>        http://localhost/js/app.js:41491:1
>       **webpack_require** http://localhost/js/app.js:20:12
>        http://localhost/js/app.js:66:18
>        http://localhost/js/app.js:1:11

Comment: It's laravel 5.4...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is the most direct way to include jQuery in both Laravel 5.4 and 5.5.
 But that may not be the only way nor the best way.
 Laravel allows at least two ways to include external or custom JS libraries.

Method A : Without Laravel Mix

Method B : With Laravel Mix (npm run dev/production)

Laravel includes jQuery using Method B, in the file `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js`.

For any changes in `resources/assets` to take effect, one would need to run `npm run dev/production` under the project directory first.
 This combines all the JS files included in `assets/js/` into a single file `public/js/app.js`, which can then be used by including

```
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

in the `<head>...</head>` block of a view.

As to the `window.Laravel is undefined` error, this

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]) !!};
</script>
```

is also required in the `<head>...</head>` of every view file that requires and **before** `public/js/app.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.5 comes with jQuery out of the box. You don't actually need to do anything.

Your error seemed to be related to its CSRF token. Referring to `window.Laravel is undefined`

Add this to the `<head></head>` section of your HTML file.

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
        'csrfToken'=>csrf_token()
    ]) !!}
</script>
```

Comment: So, Back to the question. How can i generally include JS libraries?

Comment: @MakanTayebi so when you first Laravel, you will have a file called `bootstrap.js` inside `app.js`. `bootstrap.js` has already configured jQuery right out of the box. All you need to do is to link your `app.js` script inside your HTML file and that is all you need.

Like I've said, your problem could be a Laravel CSRF token. See the answer above for the code block.